# how to solve log4j causing a memory leak?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, log4j, tomcat6, java-6

SEVERE: A web application created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@3ac5b23e]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{userhost=192.168.15.90, userid=127, username=ramzi.abdelsamad}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the ThreadLocal has been forcibly removed.

Suddenly the web server stops and when i check the logs in catalina.out this is what i find! after looking for the problem it has been told that's a memory leak caused by log4j maybe ??

does anyone has an idea ??

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MDC in your web app?

Anyway, found this [log4J memory leak](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50486)

This look like you are right!! ;-)

EDIT : What version of log4j are you using?  found out that 1.2.17 should solve this problem.